# Edit Fuzzy C means function to take Haversine formula as distance metric

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm new to r, and please correct me if what I'm asking for is impossible or insane.

I want to cluster a set of geographical coordinates data(latitude, longitude) into a predetermined number of clusters with approximately the same size.

I'm concerned with k-means and FCM algorithms since it's calculating based on euclidean distance. I'm thinking if I can substitute that with Haversine formula maybe if would work. I looked at the source code for the cmeans function, but has no idea what's going on..

My idea is to add a Haversine option under the metric method as below, and add the code accordingly.

```
  `dist <- pmatch(dist, c("euclidean", "manhattan","Haversine"))`
```

I've also tried DBSCAN, but since I need a fix number of cluster with similar size, I found it hard to achieve my goal.

Please let me know if this is possible. Any other thoughts on how I can perform the cluster is also welcomed, thanks!

```
#Fuzzy C Means
fcmeans=function (x, centers, iter.max = 100, verbose = FALSE, dist = "euclidean", 
          method = "cmeans", m = 2, rate.par = NULL, weights = 1, control = list()) 
{
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  xrows <- nrow(x)
  xcols <- ncol(x)
  if (missing(centers)) 
    stop("Argument 'centers' must be a number or a matrix.")
  dist <- pmatch(dist, c("euclidean", "manhattan"))
  if (is.na(dist)) 
    stop("invalid distance")
  if (dist == -1) 
    stop("ambiguous distance")
  method <- pmatch(method, c("cmeans", "ufcl"))
  if (is.na(method)) 
    stop("invalid clustering method")
  if (method == -1) 
    stop("ambiguous clustering method")
  if (length(centers) == 1) {
    ncenters <- centers
    centers <- x[sample(1:xrows, ncenters), , drop = FALSE]
    if (any(duplicated(centers))) {
      cn <- unique(x)
      mm <- nrow(cn)
      if (mm < ncenters) 
        stop("More cluster centers than distinct data points.")
      centers <- cn[sample(1:mm, ncenters), , drop = FALSE]
    }
  }
  else {
    centers <- as.matrix(centers)
    if (any(duplicated(centers))) 
      stop("Initial centers are not distinct.")
    cn <- NULL
    ncenters <- nrow(centers)
    if (xrows < ncenters) 
      stop("More cluster centers than data points.")
  }
  if (xcols != ncol(centers)) 
    stop("Must have same number of columns in 'x' and 'centers'.")
  if (iter.max < 1) 
    stop("Argument 'iter.max' must be positive.")
  if (method == 2) {
    if (missing(rate.par)) {
      rate.par <- 0.3
    }
  }
  reltol <- control$reltol
  if (is.null(reltol)) 
    reltol <- sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)
  if (reltol <= 0) 
    stop("Control parameter 'reltol' must be positive.")
  if (any(weights < 0)) 
    stop("Argument 'weights' has negative elements.")
  if (!any(weights > 0)) 
    stop("Argument 'weights' has no positive elements.")
  weights <- rep(weights, length = xrows)
  weights <- weights/sum(weights)
  perm <- sample(xrows)
  x <- x[perm, ]
  weights <- weights[perm]
  initcenters <- centers
  pos <- as.factor(1:ncenters)
  rownames(centers) <- pos
  if (method == 1) {
    retval <- .C("cmeans", as.double(x), as.integer(xrows), 
                 as.integer(xcols), centers = as.double(centers), 
                 as.integer(ncenters), as.double(weights), as.double(m), 
                 as.integer(dist - 1), as.integer(iter.max), as.double(reltol), 
                 as.integer(verbose), u = double(xrows * ncenters), 
                 ermin = double(1), iter = integer(1), PACKAGE = "e1071")
  }
  else if (method == 2) {
    retval <- .C("ufcl", x = as.double(x), as.integer(xrows), 
                 as.integer(xcols), centers = as.double(centers), 
                 as.integer(ncenters), as.double(weights), as.double(m), 
                 as.integer(dist - 1), as.integer(iter.max), as.double(reltol), 
                 as.integer(verbose), as.double(rate.par), u = double(xrows * 
                                                                        ncenters), ermin = double(1), iter = integer(1), 
                 PACKAGE = "e1071")
  }
  centers <- matrix(retval$centers, ncol = xcols, dimnames = list(1:ncenters, 
                                                                  colnames(initcenters)))
  u <- matrix(retval$u, ncol = ncenters, dimnames = list(rownames(x), 
                                                         1:ncenters))
  u <- u[order(perm), ]
  iter <- retval$iter - 1
  withinerror <- retval$ermin
  cluster <- apply(u, 1, which.max)
  clustersize <- as.integer(table(cluster))
  retval <- list(centers = centers, size = clustersize, cluster = cluster, 
                 membership = u, iter = iter, withinerror = withinerror, 
                 call = match.call())
  class(retval) <- c("fclust")
  return(retval)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, for starters, this function isn't using distance in the way that you are thinking. It is saying how to measure distance between points as either measured in Euclidean distance (e.g., as the crow flies) or Manhattan distance (which sticks to the gridlines of the Cartesian plane).

The problem with both methods is that they are going to compute the distance input wrong --- not that summing the squares or the Manhattan distance measures are wrong.

You can add your change to `pmatch(dist, ...` but you are going to have to also change the code that it calls out to. If you use `cmeans` (and not `ufcl`) as the value for `method`, the function calls out to the C program `cmeans` in the `e1071` package (this is what the `.C` stuff is about). You can get the source for the package off [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/index.html). Everywhere this program computes a distance from something else, you are going to want to modify it to use the Haversine formula. At the very least this includes changes to `ufcl_dissimilarities`. Once you make those changes, you are going to need to recompile the source code (`R CMD build` from the terminal).

I'm not familiar enough with the math to completely follow the `cmeans.c` program, but you may have better luck.

Unless you are familiar with C/C++/want a challenge, you are probably best off using Euclidean distance with the knowledge that it is computing the distance between points wrong. Since the error increases as the points move apart, in theory, it shouldn't hurt you too much since you are trying to place clusters such that they minimize distance.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This is way more complicated than I thought, I'll probably write my own function then..

Answer (score 0):

fuzzy c-means, just like k-means, relies on the **mean** to be consistent with your distance function.

I.e. for two points at longitude +179 and -179, they would place the mean at 0, instead of +180! This can cause the algorithm to never converge.

**Do not use *mean*-based algorithms on geo data**

If your data is local, you can project to the UTM zone, which gives a quite good Euclidean approximation. (That is the whole point of this projection, but it only works on a slice of earth at a time)

Another workaround is to use 3d space.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My data is local and falls mostly within one UTM Zone, so is mean-based algorithms acceptable?

Comment: Within one UTM it may work. Analyze the results, if they make sense. I was very disappointed with k-means, because its splits are off all the time. I don't think means are very meaningful. The mean may be right in the ocean or a lake..